# Rails Converting a has_many relationship into a has and belongs to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails app with the following relationship:

**region.rb**

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facilities
end
```

**facility.rb**

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end
```

I want to expand functionality a bit so that facilities can belong to more than one region at a time.  I believe I can do this with a has_many_through relationship but I'm needing some guidance on converting the existing has_many into a has many through.  I understand how to create and wire up the join table, but how would I take existing data and translate it?

So for instance.  On a facility object there is `region_id`, since the facilities can belong to more than one region I'd probably need a `region_ids` field and shovel the collection of regions into that column which should then populate the other side of the association via the join table.  I have this part pretty much figured out as far as moving forward and wiring up the association.  But I'm unsure as to how to take existing data and translate it over so the app doesn't break when I change the model association.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to **always** use `has_many :through` instead of HBTM.

To establish this kind of relation you'll need the following set up:

```
# region.rb
class Region
  has_many :facility_regions
  has_many :facilities, through: :facility_regions
end

# facility.rb
class Facility
  has_many :facility_regions
  has_many :regions, through: :facility_regions
end

# facility_region.rb
class FacilityRegion
  belongs_to :facility
  belongs_to :region
end
```

Also, of course, you'll need to create a migration:

```
rails g migration create_facility_regions facility_id:integer region_id:integer
# in this migration create a uniq index:
add_index :facility_regions, %I(facility_id region_id), name: :facility_region
rake db:migrate
```

## UPD

As to migration from one database state to another one.

I think it should not be a problem.

1) Do not delete the relations you had before (leave `has_many :facilities` and `belongs_to :region` in models).

2) When new table is created and new associations added to the classes (which I showed) create a new migration:

```
rails g migration migrate_database_state
```

3) Write the script, which will create new records in db (to reflect the current state of things):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  Facility.where.not(region_id: nil).find_each do |facility|
    next if FacilityRegion.find_by(falicity_id: facility.id, region_id: facility.region_id)
    FacilityRegion.create!(facility_id: facility.id, region_id: facility.region_id)
  end
end
```

4) Put this script into last created migration and run it (or in console without migration, effect would be the same).

5) After script is successfully run, create new migration in which you delete `region_id` from `facilities` table and remove these associations definitions (`has_many :facilities` and `belongs_to :region`) from models.

It must be it. I might have made some typos or so, make sure I did not miss anything and

Comment: Got it, I had this part down and understood how to wire up the middle/join table to make the association work.  My main question was after the migration and model association change how do I take the existing facilities and regions and migrate all of the data/columns so that the join table populates?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will give this a try today and post up any questions I may have.

Comment: This worked, however I had to refactor the migrate_database_state to not use find_by since this is a Rails 3.2 app.  Sorry, I should have specified.

Comment: Why would you recommend HMT over HABTM?

Comment: @RichPeck it is a subjective recommendation (truly to say simply because of habit). I used to using HMT over HABTM. It is more flexible, and sometimes it is useful to have what HMT offers.

Comment: Means you have to have another model though :)

Comment: @RichPeck True, true. But, on the other hand, more control over validations, additional attributes and stuff :)

Comment: Of course; we've been experimenting with a single "associations" model which has been very interesting

Comment: I had to create a default model.rb file to bypass migration errors, NameError: uninitialized constant MigrateDatabaseState:: to be precise. I had Users and Roles so i created user_role.rb. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another model, a "middle guy" called FacilityRegion.rb, like this:

## facility.rb

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :falicity_regions
  has_many :regions, through: falicity_regions
end
```

## facility_region.rb

```
class FacilityRegion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :facility
end
```

## region.rb

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :falicity_regions
  has_many :facilities, through: falicity_regions
end
```

Comment: Got it, I had this part down and understood how to wire up the middle/join table to make the association work. My main question was after the migration and model association change how do I take the existing facilities and regions and migrate all of the data/columns so that the join table populates?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `belongs_and_has_many` relationship, you need to:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableRegionsFacilities regions facilities
```

Then,

```
rake db:migrate
```

Now, your relationships should be:

**Region.rb:**

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :facilities
end
```

**Facility.rb**

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions
end
```

In order to populate the new join table, you will need to in your console:

```
Region.all.find_each do |r|
  Facility.where(region_id: r.id).find_each do |f|
    r.facilities <<  f
  end
end
```

Now, you can either leave the columns `region_id` and `facility_id` in Facility and Region table, respectively, or you can create a migration to delete it.

Comment: This is exactly what i need, but how about i do not wish to run the code to populate the join table in the console, how do i add it to the migration file so it populates the table after the table is created?

Comment: Hello, @chrisgeeq. From my knowledge, it's not common to populate your database with the migration file. The best practice that I know, if you don't want to do it via console is to create a rake task. Check this https://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/ . To schedule a task, you can use the whenever gem (https://github.com/javan/whenever). But, if you are using Heroku, you should use Heroku Scheduler (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)